# Lets Encrypt gives 'Site cannot be reached' message

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, https, openssl, lets-encrypt

I have installed letsencrypt and got success message:
Have following in my example.com-le.ssl.conf file:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin abc@gmail.com
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/path
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
<Directory /var/www/html/path>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

default-ssl.conf also points to 443.

Firewall status shows following:

```
443/tcp                    ALLOW       Anywhere
Apache Full                ALLOW       Anywhere
OpenSSH                    ALLOW       Anywhere
443/tcp (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
Apache Full (v6)           ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
OpenSSH (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

Then, when i give https://example.com, it gives error message, 'Site cannot be reached'. But, http://example.com works fine. What can be wrong with https configuration??

Comment: Do you use the verification method via port 80? If yes you have to open and provide that port.

Comment: @Robert - How can i do that?

Comment: That depends on the used Let's Encrypt client. read the documentation: https://letsencrypt.org/docs/client-options/